# Osmdroid offline mode update tiles after zoom

Tags: android, osmdroid, android-mapview

I'm developing an Android app that uses Osmdroid to display the maps in offline mode. I have an issue when I want to zoom in or out by pinching on the map or using the build-in zoomcontrols. When I zoom in the map tiles are not always correctly rendered and when I zoom out the sometimes there are some gray tiles in the map, sometimes everything is rendered OK. It's not related on the location displayed on the map. My map tiles are stored in an osmdroid zip-file with the Mapnik source in the folder /mnt/sdcard/osmdroid. I'm using osmdroid-3.0.7.

So, any help is welcome.

See my code below (my includes aren't included here in the code):

```
public class MapActivity extends OSMapActivity {

private ArrayList<String[]> mapPointData;
private ArrayList<String[]> multiData;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.map);

    setABTitle(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("geoLoc")[0]);
    actionButtonVisible(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("routeList"));

    initLayout();
    setHomePoint();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Prefs.clearMapPrefs(this);
}

private void initLayout() {

    c = this;
    // Buttons @ top of the activity
    doseeBN = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeBN);
    eatdrinkBN = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapEatdrinkBN);
    nightlifeBN = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapNightlifeBN);
    sleepBN = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapSleepBN);

    // The LinearLayout with the ScrollView for the Subcategories in "Do & See"
    doseeLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.doseeSubCatLL);
    top10BN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeTop10BN);
    monumentsBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeMonumentsBN);
    museumBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeMuseumsBN);
    cultureBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeCultureBN);
    attractionsBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeAttractionBN);
    shoppingBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeShoppingBN);
    marketBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapDoseeMarketBN);

    // Init of the map an mapcontroller
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.osmMV);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
   // mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


    mapData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    mapPointData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    multiData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
}

private void setHomePoint() {
    //GeoPoint centerPt = new GeoPoint(50.89489, 4.34140); // Point of Grand Place Brussels

    homeLat = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("geoLoc")[1]);
    homeLong = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("geoLoc")[2]);

    GeoPoint centerPt = new GeoPoint(homeLat, homeLong);

    if (checkMapRange(Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("geoLoc")[1]), 
            Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("geoLoc")[2]))) {
        mapController.setCenter(centerPt);

        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pin_marker);

        ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        items.add(new OverlayItem("Here I am!", "Hello", centerPt));
        ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> itemOverlay = 
                                new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, marker, null, new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this));
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
    } else {
        mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(50.89489, 4.34140));
        mapController.setZoom(11);
        Action.alert(this, getResources().getString(R.string.alert_title_notinregion), 
                getResources().getString(R.string.alert_message_notinregion), false);
        mapView.setClickable(false);
    }
}

public void onClickMapPointsBN(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.mapDoseeBN:
        setPrefsCategory("DOSEE", doseeBN, "btn_map_dosee", "btn_map_dosee_pressed");
        break;
    case R.id.mapEatdrinkBN:
        setPrefsCategory("EATDRINK", eatdrinkBN, "btn_map_eatdrink", "btn_map_eatdrink_pressed");
        break;
    case R.id.mapNightlifeBN:
        setPrefsCategory("NIGHTLIFE", nightlifeBN, "btn_map_nightlife", "btn_map_nightlife_pressed");
        break;
    case R.id.mapSleepBN:
        setPrefsCategory("SLEEP", sleepBN, "btn_map_sleep", "btn_map_sleep_pressed");
        break;
    }

    setPOIs();
}

public void onClickDoseeListBN(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.mapDoseeTop10BN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[0], top10BN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapDoseeMuseumsBN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[2], museumBN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapDoseeCultureBN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[3], cultureBN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapDoseeAttractionBN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[4], attractionsBN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapDoseeShoppingBN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[5], shoppingBN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapDoseeMarketBN:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[6], marketBN);
        break;
    default:
        setDosseSubCat(Definitions.doseeList[1], monumentsBN);
        break;
    }

    setPOIs();
}

private void setPrefsCategory(String cat, ImageView btn, String image, String imageSelected) {
    boolean sel = Prefs.getBoolean(this, "map" + cat, false);

    Prefs.setBoolean(this, "map" + cat, !sel);
    setCategoryImage(btn, image, imageSelected, sel);

    if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("DOSEE")) {
        if (sel) {
            doseeLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            doseeLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            for (String s : Definitions.doseeList) {
                if (s.equals(Definitions.doseeList[1])) {
                    Prefs.setBoolean(this, "mapDS_" + s, true);
                } else {
                    Prefs.setBoolean(this, "mapDS_" + s, false);
                }
            }
        }

        setSubcategoryColor(sel);
    }
}

private void setCategoryImage(ImageView btn, String image, String imageSelected, boolean selected) {
    String devLang = Prefs.getString(this, "devLanguage", "en");

    if (!devLang.equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
        image += "_" + devLang;
        imageSelected += "_" + devLang;
    }

    if (selected) {
        btn.setImageResource(this.getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    } else {
        btn.setImageResource(this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageSelected, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    }
}

private void setSubcategoryColor(boolean doseeSelected) {
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, top10BN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(doseeSelected, monumentsBN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, museumBN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, cultureBN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, attractionsBN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, shoppingBN);
    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(true, marketBN);
}

private void setPOIs() {
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.invalidate();
    mapData.clear();

    setHomePoint();

    boolean selected;

    for (String category : Definitions.categoryList) {
        selected = Prefs.getBoolean(this, "map" + category, false);

        Log.d("VB.Map", "Category: " + category + " selected: " + selected);
        if (selected) {
            if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("DOSEE")) {
                boolean subSelected;

                for (String subcategory : Definitions.doseeList) {
                    subSelected = Prefs.getBoolean(this, "mapDS_" + subcategory, false);

                    if (subSelected) {
                        getSqlData(category, subcategory);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                getSqlData(category, null);
            }
        }
    }

    removeMapDataItems();
    //mapPointData = mapData;
    //multiDataLocationSelector();
    setMapDataPoints();
    //setMultiMapPoints();
}

private void getSqlData(String category, String subCategory) {
    ArrayList<String[]> sqlData = SqlDB.db.getCategoryItems(Adjust.rewriteCategoryName(category), subCategory);

    for (String[] data : sqlData) {
        mapData.add(data);
    }
}

private void removeMapDataItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++) {
        if ((mapData.get(i)[13].equalsIgnoreCase("")) || (mapData.get(i)[14].equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
            mapData.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

private void setDosseSubCat(String subCat, Button btn) {
    boolean selected = Prefs.getBoolean(this, "mapDS_" + subCat, false);

    Prefs.setBoolean(this, "mapDS_" + subCat, !selected);

    setDoseeSubCatTextColor(selected, btn);
}

private void setDoseeSubCatTextColor(boolean selected, Button btn) {
    if (selected) {
        btn.setTextColor(Definitions.colorDoseeSubcat);
    } else {
        btn.setTextColor(Definitions.colorDoseeSubcatSelected);
    }
}

private void setMapDataPoints() {
    if (mapData != null) {
        ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        OverlayItem overlayItem;

        for (String[] item : mapData) {
            multiData.add(item);
            if (existsInOverlayItems(item, mapOverlays)) {
                overlayItem = new OverlayItem("-1", "", new GeoPoint(Float.parseFloat(item[13]), Float.parseFloat(item[14])));
                overlayItem.setMarker(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pin_multiple));
            } else {
                overlayItem = new OverlayItem(item[0], "", new GeoPoint(Float.parseFloat(item[13]), Float.parseFloat(item[14])));
                overlayItem.setMarker(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(item[15], "drawable", getPackageName())));
            }

            mapOverlays.add(overlayItem);
        }

        setMapOverlays(mapOverlays);
    }
}

private boolean existsInOverlayItems(String[] item, ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < overlayItemList.size(); i++) {
        if ((new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(item[13]), Double.parseDouble(item[14]))).equals(overlayItemList.get(i).mGeoPoint)) {
            overlayItemList.remove(i);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void setMapOverlays(ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlays) {  
    ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> itemOverlays = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
            overlays, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pin_marker), new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

        public boolean onItemLongPress(int arg0, OverlayItem item) {
            mapOverlayItemPressed(Integer.parseInt(item.mTitle), item);
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int arg0, OverlayItem item) {
            mapOverlayItemPressed(Integer.parseInt(item.mTitle), item);
            return false;
        }
    }, new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this));


    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemOverlays);

    mapView.invalidate();
}

private void mapOverlayItemPressed(int itemId, OverlayItem overlayItem) {
    if (itemId == -1) {
        Collect.multiPOIList.clear();

        for (String[] item : multiData) {
            if ((new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(item[13]), Double.parseDouble(item[14]))).equals(overlayItem.mGeoPoint)) {
                Collect.multiPOIList.add(item);
            }
        }

        Action.alertWithListView(this, getResources().getString(R.string.alert_title_multiplepoi), false);

    } else {
        SqlDB.db.getItemsById(itemId);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("listSelection", 0);

        Action.newIntent(c, DetailActivity.class, b);
    }
}

private boolean checkMapRange(double lat, double lng) {
    double mapLatMax = 50.922085;
    double mapLatMin = 50.781631;
    double mapLongMin = 4.240723;
    double mapLongMax = 4.490662;

    if ((lat > mapLatMin) && (lat < mapLatMax)) {
        if ((lng > mapLongMin) && (lng < mapLongMax)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And here the code of the OSMapActivity:

```
public class OSMapActivity extends ActionbarActivity {

protected Context c;

protected MapView mapView;
protected MapController mapController;
protected ArrayList<String[]> mapData;

protected ImageView doseeBN;
protected ImageView eatdrinkBN;
protected ImageView nightlifeBN;
protected ImageView sleepBN;
protected LinearLayout doseeLL;

protected Button top10BN;
protected Button monumentsBN;
protected Button museumBN;
protected Button cultureBN;
protected Button attractionsBN;
protected Button shoppingBN;
protected Button marketBN;

protected double homeLat;
protected double homeLong;

public void onClickABActionButton(View v) {
    boolean actionButton = Prefs.getBoolean(this, "abActionButtonRoute", false);

    if (actionButton) {
        // TODO Add with current location => location manager in separate class
        /*GPS.init(this);
        GPS.enableGPSProvider();
        GPS.enableNetworkProvider();
        //Action.loadApp(this, Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:50.89489,4.34140?daddr=Heiveld+21+Opwijk"));
        Action.loadApp(this, Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + GPS.latitude + "," + GPS.longitude
                                                            + "&daddr=Heiveld+21+1745+Opwijk"));
        GPS.stop();*/
        Action.loadMapsWithMyLocation(this, homeLat, homeLong);
    } else {
        Collect.dbList.clear();

        for (String[] data : mapData) {
            Collect.dbList.add(data);
        }

        // TODO Load new intent with list
        Action.newIntent(this, MapListActivity.class, null);

    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Kr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I raised an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=289&can=1&sort=-id) on version 3.0.6 about this. In the comments the authors say it was fixed on Feb 1st. As the 3.0.7 jar is dated Jan 29, I assume the fix isn't in it. I'm sticking with version 3.0.5 for now, although the cycle maps don't work in it and the tile loading can be a bit flickery. If your maps are offline though, they should load pretty fast and flicker might not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very helpful answer. I've replaced the osmdroid-api with version 3.0.5 and now it's working fine. Maybe a little bit flickery, but it doesn't disturb in my app. I've lso reported again as a bug in version 3.0.7 to the osmdroid-team. So, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the same problem as reported here:

[OSMDroid Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/osmdroid/browse_frm/thread/c5e3a8ddff041350?hl=en)

If so then the solution (for now) seems to be to download the current OSMDroid source and build your own .jar library.
No changes to the source are required BUT the tile loading problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but building the latest osmdroid 4.2 doesn't help. I think it is the issue mentioned by @NickT, and it is still unresolved ((